# How do I ensure the contents of my flex div stay within it's container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flexbox div with 3 items in it. Its direction is column.

The flexbox div doesn't have height, but its container has a max-height.

The maxheight works for the container, but the middle item in the flexbox div is huge and goes way outside the bounds of it's container.

Here's a codepen illustrating my issue:
http://codepen.io/jaman4dbz/pen/BWedNN

You'll see the body has a computed height of 600px or some such (depending on your window height), while the app div is waaaaay larger.

The ultimate goal is to have the large div stretch the contents of the flex div until it reaches max-height, then stop. Essentially I want the middle large div to be responsive.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { 
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0; 
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

.twocol {
    display: flex;
}

.app {
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 100vh; */
    background: cadetblue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: auto;
}

/**
 * Note that this demo will actually work fine in IE10. This is because in IE10, flex-shrink is 0 instead of 1.  See: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed
 **/
.header {
    width: 100%;
    background: orchid;
}

/**
 * 1. IE needs display: block on the main element.
 * 2. IE10 sets flex-shrink to 0. This was originally according to spec, but has since changed. See: https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#6-the-default-flex-value-has-changed
 **/
.main {
    display: block; /* 1 */
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1; /* 2 */
    background: blanchedalmond;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: coral;
}

h1 { font-size: 36px; }
p { font-size: 16px; }
```

```html
<body class="twocol">
    <div class="app">
        <header class="header">
            <p>Hello</p>
        </header>
        <main class="main">
            <h1>Cupcake ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
            <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps. Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>        <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps. Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>        <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps. Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>        <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps. Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>        <p>Fruitcake macaroon candy canes marshmallow gummi bears biscuit I love dessert. Oat cake sugar plum marzipan gummi bears marshmallow I love brownie jelly bonbon. Sweet roll apple pie wafer fruitcake. Gummi bears lemon drops sesame snaps. Biscuit tiramisu sugar plum. Carrot cake pastry cupcake tootsie roll chocolate jujubes. Pudding muffin sweet. Cheesecake candy canes wafer gingerbread sweet.</p>
            <p>Liquorice candy canes cake. Gummies wafer tart topping pastry soufflé I love pie. Cake cookie croissant cupcake chocolate cake. Liquorice jelly beans pudding sugar plum biscuit fruitcake. Soufflé tootsie roll macaroon pudding. Chocolate cake cake sesame snaps sugar plum biscuit I love croissant icing. Caramels jelly dessert candy bonbon bear claw chocolate bar cheesecake icing. Toffee I love cake gingerbread jelly-o tootsie roll. Sesame snaps pie cupcake sweet. Croissant danish brownie gummies lollipop chupa chups gummies danish.</p>
            <p>Chupa chups pudding topping caramels pie. Tart jujubes ice cream muffin sugar plum. Soufflé candy canes I love lollipop pastry brownie danish apple pie. Apple pie chupa chups biscuit chocolate bar I love muffin I love. Caramels cupcake I love sugar plum icing candy canes I love macaroon. Marzipan danish cheesecake marshmallow jelly. Jelly-o sugar plum liquorice donut I love pastry candy donut. I love gummi bears chocolate.</p>
            <p>Gingerbread toffee pastry gingerbread I love toffee. Biscuit jelly wafer I love cheesecake candy canes chocolate cake. I love cake I love cotton candy muffin oat cake I love I love. I love bonbon macaroon toffee powder chupa chups cotton candy tootsie roll chocolate. Croissant dessert chocolate bar. Apple pie I love croissant sugar plum cotton candy I love. Candy canes jelly I love. Jelly beans cupcake brownie pudding lemon drops</p>
            <p>Cheesecake macaroon toffee sesame snaps cotton candy cotton candy I love. Cake sugar plum sweet marshmallow I love. Soufflé liquorice ice cream candy canes I love tootsie roll marzipan biscuit jelly. I love I love tiramisu donut. I love bear claw pastry toffee. Cheesecake apple pie bonbon bear claw jelly-o topping tootsie roll chocolate bar. Cake bonbon toffee donut macaroon chocolate lemon drops gummies gummies. Jelly beans chocolate bar cotton candy halvah fruitcake.</p>
        </main>
        <footer class="footer">
            Goodbye
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div>Col2</div>
</body>
```

Comment: If something is too big to fit of course it overflows. What do you want it to do when it does is the question?

Comment: Why not just use `height: 100vh` on `.app`? You have it commented out, but that solves the problem. (And, incidentally, you then don't need `height: 100vh` on `body`.)

Comment: The example is confusing. I have a better one I made. I'll post a new question with the better example.

Comment: @Paulie_D .main { overflow: auto } should create a scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was a lack of inheriting all forms of height.
I needed to set height: inherit AND max-height: inherit for every div between my modal and my large div. React can burn you with extra divs sometimes.

Here is the final code pen that works:
http://codepen.io/jaman4dbz/pen/LWozeZ

```
.unnecessary {
  height: inherit;
  max-height: inherit;
}

.allstuff {
  display: flex;
  height: inherit;
  max-height: inherit;
}

.twocol {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

EDIT: This solution comes with a caveat. You can't have any padding on the div with height and you can't have a margin on it's immediate children. If you do, your child element well go outside the bounds of it's parent, because it has the same height, evem though it's meant to be squeezed into a smaller area.

Comment: It's not really a React issue. The CSS `height` property does not inherit values by default. See the property definition in the spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#the-height-property

Comment: It's a react issue by component design. React doesn't insert the divs, the developers do, because every component needs a containing element.

This means all of our nicely divided components cause a lot of divs, and requires a lot of 'inherit'ed values.

Answer (score 1):

Set `html, body, .app { height: 100%; }` (and remove all other height settings for those elements). It's necessary to set `html` as well as the other two.

Comment: That almost worked! Here's the better example im working with.
http://codepen.io/jaman4dbz/pen/GWaMZW

Although I think I'm going to rewrite my question, because I know more specifically what the problem is.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do anymore -- you're `display:flex`ing containers with only one element in them. But the new 'pen looks better if you add `.twocol { overflow: hidden; max-height: 100%; }`

Comment: ya, I think the css for my main project is simply broken. My latest code pen works as i intend it:
http://codepen.io/jaman4dbz/pen/LWozeZ

Sorry for not  being more useful with my question, however, strangely, you did lead me to a solution through height: 100%.

I'm going to try and wack through our jungle of thousands of lines of sass to see what is breaking the styles.

I'll be back with a solution, which well probably be so specific as to be useless to SO =P

Comment: The trick is to inherit all the things. Very similar to height: 100% in theory.

Thanks again for your help Blaze!